# Change animation duration CSS3 not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, animation

I have this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/CarlosGHM/W3MPj/9/). When you click div duration animation must change but it does not work on Chrome.

This is my js code:

```
var seconds = 1;
function ChangeSpeed(){
    seconds++;
    document.getElementById('rectangle').style.animationDuration = seconds+"s";
}
```

And this is my css:

```
div#rectangle{
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    background:black;
    -webkit-animation: ShapeRotate; 
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s; 
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear; 
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-play-state: running;
}

@-webkit-keyframes ShapeRotate {
    from {
      -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to { 
      -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

I also tried this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/CarlosGHM/dRr9m/4/) on Firefox and it works!

I can not figure out why this is not working on Chrome.

My Chrome version is *35.0.1916.153 (Build oficial 274914) m*

Comment: It works for me in Chrome (24). [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dRr9m/7/).

Comment: Yes, it works in older versions of Chrome. I ran a test on this site: https://browserling.com/ with my JSFiddle. Should i report this as a bug to Google Chrome team?

Answer (score 1):

I Think I've found your mistake.

On your fiddle the code appears like this

```
var seconds = 1;
function ChangeSpeed(){
    seconds++;
    document.getElementById('rectangle').style.mozAnimationDuration = seconds+"s";
}
```

I think that you should add compatibility to all browsers. Your mistake is on:

```
style.mozAnimationDuration
```

and you should put `style.webkitAnimationDuration` for Chrome compatibility and so on for other browsers.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug reported the Aug 3, 2014 : [link](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=399950).

It was fixed and released the Feb 2, 2015 : [Blink Revision 189311](https://src.chromium.org/viewvc/blink?revision=189311&view=revision).

PS : use chrome://version/ for know your blink version.